# iOS scroll view is not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a button at the 1000 height pixel mark and I need a uiscrollview in order to access that button. I implemented the scrollview code below and it shows the scroll view ,but doesn't allow me to scroll down. I might be missing a key function. Any tips or advice is appreciated.

```
 UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 680)];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
super.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[[self view] addSubview:scrollView];
```

Comment: Are you using Auto-Layout?

Comment: Where are you running this code?? In `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Yes, I am using auto layout and viewdidload.

Comment: @TwoFace Try turning off auto-layout

Comment: The error is likely somewhere else in your code. I copied this into my project, and it is working perfectly except that 680 is much larger than the screen size (on iPhone 4S Retina Simulator).

Comment: are you running this on iPhone or iPad? if iphone, then it'll certainly not scroll all the way to the top. the scrollView.frame.size.height should not exceed it's parentView height.

Comment: Try setting the `contentSize` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLoad:`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your button's y coordinate is 1000 pixels, as you have stated. And the  y-coordinate of scrollview's contentZize is maximum upto 1000 pixels as well. So the scrollview can jus scroll up to exactly where the button starts.

```
UIButton *btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(50, 1000, 100,45);
[scrollView addSubview:btn];
```

set the content size of scrollview like this

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1100);
```

This will surely solve it.